# Knockout js no me trae el valor de la fecha establecido?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

tengo inconvenientes al traer una fecha desde la base de datos con knockout, me trae la siguiente fecha,

```
function genderModel() {
    var genderModel = this;

    genderModel.GenderId = ko.observable();
    genderModel.GenderName = ko.observable();
    genderModel.CreateBy = ko.observable();
    genderModel.CreationDate = ko.observable();
    genderModel.ModifiedBy = ko.observable();
    genderModel.ModifiedDate = ko.observable();
}
```

coloque un alert y me trae el siguiente valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me trae la fecha que tiene el objecto, ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se en qué parte de su código está disparando la siguiente alerta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, si genera una variable de tipo `Date` puede obtener el valor correcto de la fecha.

Para el caso de `Date(1546259813993)`, el valor es: `"2018-12-31T12:36:53.993Z"`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var dd = new Date(1546259813993);
console.log(dd);
```